# Is a toasty preserved ok during trip if in a backpack?

Tags: bread, food-preservation, turkey, toasting

When making toasted bread with filling such as turkey slices etc (toasted as well) with avocado spread, is there any problem of having it in a backpack while on a trip and eating it after few hours?
I was referring to if there is a chance that it could go bad?

Comment: @moscafj: that post is too general while my question is very specific and I think it is reasonable to assume lots of people do something similar. If I take that post and apply it directly to my question the only answer would be it is unsafe which I don't believe that it is true as multiple people carry sandwitches and toasts with them. I am interested if they are doing some specific preparation to make sure all is ok

Comment: Hi Jim, if you already believe to know the answer, there is no point in asking the question. But it seems that there is a misunderstanding here: the site only covers official guidelines about food safety. Many people don't know them and have a personal opinion on what is safe, and act on that opinion - but this is irrelevant on our site. If you want to go by official guidelines, you have to accept what the linked question says. If you don't want that, you will have to ask the question somewhere else, on sites which allow subjective opinions.

Comment: @Jim if you can prepare and carry your sandwiches within the guidelines collected in the linked question, you can work to ensure safety.  ...and that is the best we can do here.

Comment: @rumtscho: The only answer I think I know is that people carry sandwiches and toasts with them. I don't know in what time interval they are consuming them or if they are packing them in a specific way. The problem with the post with the general guidelines is that in my interpretation it suggests that the best is to consume everything right away and not keep left overs otherwise too many factors have to be taken into account.

Comment: @Jim your interpretation of the linked post is correct. Once you make your sandwiches, they are only safe for 2 hours without refrigeration. The official food safety rules do not make any differing provisions or consider any other factors.

Comment: @rumtscho : people have been packing lunches for decades if not centuries.  And it sits for way longer than two hours before it gets eaten.  The 2 hour rule comes from restaurants, where something going wrong could sicken hundreds.  Yes, it might be warmer now than when I was a kid, but things don’t magically go bad 120 minutes after they’ve been out of the fridge.  Especially cured meats.

Comment: @jim : if we can’t get this reopened (as there are a slew of questions on here about transporting food), then you might want to try asking it it on outdoors.SE, as every day hiker would have the same issues.

Comment: See also: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/86228/67

Comment: @Joe, the question you linked discusses keeping items cold, and also refers back the the very same duplicate answer linked here. Food safety is about both time and temperature, not about locations, such as restaurants.   You can spin it any way you like, but the food safety rules don't change.

Comment: @Jim nobody said that it "magically goes bad" - it becomes unsafe as specified in food safety rules. Again: it appears that you are looking for an answer that uses other criteria than official food safety rules. In that case, our site is the wrong place for you, since that would be off topic for us.

Comment: @rumtscho: That wasn't my comment (I am the one who wrote the post)

Comment: @Joe: Sounds good to me. Your comment also makes a lot of sense to me, as my personal experience does not really support that very strict guidelines